# How to embed a document .docx, .doc and .xlsx, .xls in web page without using Google docs or any other viewer platform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, documentviewer

I need to show excel and word documents in browser; but the computer has no internet access so I cannot use a cloud-based viewer like Google Docs.

I tried to use [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/)  but its not working for certain document types such as `docx` and `xlsx`

Is there a recommendation for other viewers that can handle these document types?

Comment: Reformatted and removed unnecessary words.

Answer (score 1):

convert docx or xlsx to pdf using libreoffice as service

Then render that .pdf in viewer.js or just iframe it into your web application